# Export to Excel throws error at SaveAs only in web-application

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to export data from my web-application to Excel

This is my class `ExcelExport`

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static class ExcelExport
{
    public static void ExportDataTableToExcel(DataTable table, string filePath, bool overwrite = false)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            if (overwrite)
                File.Delete(filePath);
            else return;
        }

        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();

        excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;

        for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;

        for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
            excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();

        excelWorkBook.SaveAs(filePath);
        excelWorkBook.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();         
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("test");
        table.Columns.AddRange(
            new []
            {
                new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string))
            }
        );

        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["Id"] = 1;
        row["Name"] = "Me";

        table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 1);

        ExportDataTableToExcel(table, @"c:\temp\bla.xlsx", true);
    }

}
```

As you can see, there is also a Main-method. When I try to run this as console-application, this works fine. 
When I run this in my web-application (calling the same function with same parameters, even calling the `Main()`) I'm getting following exception at the `excelWorkBook.SaveAs(filePath);`:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Any idea what could go wrong? Or you know any workarounds?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 (TL;DR - don't use Excel from a web app)

Comment: @mjwills yeah heard of **dont use excel in web app** but there arent that many options. after debugging: the filepath is correct, shows `c:\\temp\\bla.xlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to make this work:

Instead of `SaveAs` you can use `excelWorkBook.SaveCopyAs(filePath);` and it works.
Not sure why this works in another way/better than `SaveAs`, but it works.